# Union of texture data pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, directx-11, unions

I capture texture data from different sources where the data is either in BYTE* or ID3D11Texture2D COM pointer, Thus I have tried to make an STL container which will contain a collection of following union type.

```
    _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ID3D11Texture2D, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D));

    union TextureData
    {
        ID3D11Texture2DPtr m_tex2D;
        BYTE* m_byte;
    };
```

But when I compile just the above declaration without using the union type to the STL container, I see the following warning:

> warning C4624:  '....::TextureData': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted

Would anyone please let me know what should I concern about declaring this union?

EDIT:

I was planning to use like this, but the compile warning is showed before using it following way:

```
std::array< std::tuple<< DXGI_FORMAT, TextureData>>, 4>;
```

EDIT2:

I have found that IF I use like below the warning does not show:

```
    union TextureData
    {
        ID3D11Texture2D* m_tex2D;
        BYTE* m_byte;
    };
```

Comment: Which "STL container" are you talking about? You need to extract and provide a [mcve], your question is considered off-topic without it.

Comment: Unions doesn't work the way you seem to think they work. Since all members share memory, there's no guarantee that `m_byte` will be a null pointer is you set `m_tex2D`. What's worse is that you can only read the member you last wrote to, so if you use `m_tex2D` then your `IsByte` function can't be used since it uses the wrong member, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: If I don't use the IsByte(), The case I do know which one to call during implementation then it will be correct right? @Someprogrammerdude You gave me a helpful info that how it works but I also want to know why the warning is showing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I mentioned above that the warning shows just to declare the union type. Is not that enough? I can't just paste unnecessary code which is not related to my issue.

Comment: problem when you use member of union with constructor/destructor. it will be not called auto and need use explicit destructor calls. so use only without constructor/destructor - like in edit2

Comment: [*if any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor , copy constructor, move constructor , copy assignment operator, move assignment operator , or destructor , the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted  for the union. — end note*](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [union documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor), **that function is deleted by default** in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

This rule makes a lot of sense if you remember that *C++ does not track the active member of a union*, thus when a union is destructed, it does not know, destructor of which member to call. Of course, if all members have trivial destructors, this does not matter.

From the [_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class?view=vs-2019):

> A smart pointer is usually referenced by the typedef definition provided by the _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF macro. This macro takes an interface name and the IID and declares **a specialization of _com_ptr_t** with the name of the interface plus a suffix of Ptr.

From the sources of [_com_ptr_t](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/um/comip.h#L287):

```
    // If we still have an interface then Release() it. The interface
    // may be NULL if Detach() has previously been called, or if it was
    // never set.
    //
    ~_com_ptr_t() throw()
    {
        _Release();
    }
```

As you can see, `_com_ptr_t` has a non-trivial destructor, so you need to add an explicit destructor to your union. This is one of the rare situations where you need to manually call destructors on objects. Something like this:

```
    union TextureData
    {
        ID3D11Texture2DPtr m_tex2D;
        BYTE* m_byte;

        ~TextureData() {
            if (/* m_tex2D is the active member */)
                m_tex2D.~_com_ptr_t();
        }
    };
```

Note that since `TextureData` does not track its active member, you need to identify whether `m_text2D` is active or not by yourself.

Another approach you can utilize is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of raw union. Contrary to a union, a variant *does* track the active member (an "alternative") and calls the appropriate destructor for you.

Comment: I will try the use of std::variant and as you said  "... so you need to add an explicit destructor to your union." Would you give an example for that case?

Comment: You need either to add a destructor to the union, or use std::variant, but not both. Anyway, I added the destructor example.